# How to generate a private key for Ethereum from the mnemonic?

Tags: dart, ethereum

I generated a new mnemonic using [bip39](https://pub.dev/packages/bip39) package: `bip39.generateMnemonic()`. There is the next step where I need to convert it into 64 characters of hex-string. I can make it using SHA-256 but it looks little weirdly because of I will apply ECDSA-256 and KECCAK-256 to generate a public key.

Is it right way to generate a private key from the mnemonic using SHA-256? Or should I use another hash-function?

**P.S.** I am a noobie in Ethereum system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BIP-39 covers only *the seed*. You also need BIP-32 and BIP-44, as one seed generates several private and public key pairs, also known as hierarchical deterministic wallet.

[You can find more information in this blog post](https://wolovim.medium.com/ethereum-201-hd-wallets-11d0c93c87f7).

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called `tweetNacl` that have several functionalities including generating a keyPair from a seed. It is also available in dart as `pineNacl` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/pinenacl).

I have not tried the dart one myself but you should be able to generate a keyPair from a seed. You can also see conversion of mnemonic into a `32-byte` seed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48437/how-to-generate-deterministic-keypairs-using-ed25519/48454)

After scrolling through some really confusing documentation of its dart implementation. You should be able to generate a keyPair from a seed with something like a function like [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/pinenacl/latest/api_authenticated_encryption/PrivateKey/PrivateKey.fromSeed.html)